# Sorting an array based on a condition

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
$records = array(

    array("postId"=>"1","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"2","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"3","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"4","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"5","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"6","grid"=>"12"),
    array("postId"=>"7","grid"=>"3"),

);
```

I want to sort this array in a way that the sum of any number of back to back "grids" is equals to 12.

Example: The values of the "grids" in the above array are : 6,3,6,3,3,12,3

(6+6=12), (3+3+3+3=12),(12=12) so the new order should be `6,6,3,3,3,3,12` or `3,3,3,3,12,6,6` or `6,3,3,6,3,3,12`

So after sorting the array the new array should look like following:

```
$records=array(

    array("postId"=>"1","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"3","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"2","grid"=>"3"),       
    array("postId"=>"4","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"5","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"7","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"6","grid"=>"12"),

);
```

I searched in php manual and found these functions: sort,uasort, uksort, usort but I couldn't figure out how to use them.

Could you please tell me how to achieve this using PHP ?

### Update

The value of grid will always be 3 or 6 or 12 (these three numbers only )

### Problem

```
  $records = array(

    array("postId"=>"1","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"2","grid"=>"6"),    
    array("postId"=>"3","grid"=>"3"),     
    array("postId"=>"4","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"5","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"6","grid"=>"6"),    
    array("postId"=>"7","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"8","grid"=>"6"),

 );
```

Comment: There's no silver bullet for this, it's going to require you write a pretty extensive function from scratch.

Comment: Would IDs 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6 also be acceptable? What is the preferred one?

Comment: *any number of back to back "grids"* => what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: You probably can't do this using php's sort functions since those functions assume there's a way of comparing two objects and determining which one is bigger or smaller. In your example, you don't have a notion of one object being greater than or smaller than another. Rather, you are trying to group based on their grid values adding up to 12.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel IDs are not an issue here :) thanks for your reply

Comment: I meant the order of the IDs... in my example 6+3+3, 6+3+3, 12.

Comment: Does the order have to be 6,6,3,3,3,3,12 or just any order that adds to 12?  If the order is important, what makes the decision that it's 6 3 12, and what about values in between?

Comment: @TravisO No the order doesn't have to be 6,6,3,3,3,3,12 . Any order that adds to 12 is okay. To make it easier I can tell you that the grid values will always be 3 or 6 or 12 (these three numbers only)

Comment: @WolfgangStengel Any order that adds to 12 is okay :)

Comment: @black_belt if it is only `3,6,12` then you can sort it in ascending / descending order so you will get `3,3,3,3,6,6,12` or `12,6,6,3,3,3,3`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller :) but the array is not fixed so this `3,3,3,3,6,6,12` can be `3,3,3,3,6,6,12,3,12,6,3,12,6,3,6.....`

Comment: that would not matter as long as there are even number of sixes and number of threes is dividable by four (or the edge case of one odd six and pair of threes).

Comment: @black_belt, You asked for something like `3+3+3+3=12`, `6+6=12`, `12=12` when you add `grids`, isn't it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera Yes you are right. but the array is not fixed to this 3,3,3,3,6,6,12 it can be very long.

Comment: @black_belt, `length` doesn't matter, does it, can you gimme an example of an array that you might get.

Comment: @SheikhHeera just imagine a very long array that consist 3,6 and 12 (Grids) in random order

Comment: @black_belt, [check this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8emFTO) and let me know if you want same result (12), because this definitely won't give you `12` after addition, is this really you want (there are 12 times `3`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are not really sorting, but reordering to create sequence. I imagine that you are trying to do some layout of bricks with fixed height, and you need to have it reordered to fill each row and leave the rest at the end. With given fixed variants of `12,6,3` it can be done by sorting it in descending order - with odd number of sixes it will be filled with smaller threes. However such order will produce boring layout - to have it more interesting you only need to reorder some posts. For this you will need to create temporary container and merge it when sum of its grids is equal 12. If you are left with some temporary containers, merge them into one and sort descending before merging with previously grouped.

Code illustrating my concept:

```php
//auxiliary function to calculate sum of grids in given temporary container
    function reduc($a) {
    return array_reduce($a, function ($result, $item) {
        return $result . $item['grid'] . ',';
    }, '');
}

function regroup($records, $group_sum = 12) {
    $temp = array();
    $grouped = array();

    foreach ($records as $r) {
        if ($r['grid'] == $group_sum) {
            $grouped[] = $r;
        } else {
            if (!$temp) {
                $temp[] = array($r);
            } else {
                $was_grouped = false;
                foreach ($temp as $idx => $container) {
                    $current_sum = sum_collection($container);
                    if ($current_sum + $r['grid'] <= $group_sum) {
                        $temp[$idx][] = $r;
                        if ($current_sum + $r['grid'] == $group_sum) {
                            $grouped = array_merge($grouped, $temp[$idx]);
                            unset($temp[$idx]);
                        }
                        $was_grouped = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$was_grouped) {
                    $temp[] = array($r);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($temp) {
        //Sort descending, so biggest ones will be filled first with smalller
        $rest = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $temp);
        usort($rest, function($a, $b) {
            return $b['grid'] - $a['grid'];
        });
        $grouped = array_merge($grouped, $rest);
    }

    return $grouped;
}
```

Comment: How did you understand that I am trying to create a layout? This is exactly what I am trying to do :) . Descending  the order was really producing a boring layout. Your code is very intelligent and produces what I exactly wanted. May be I couldn't explain everything
clearly in my question but somehow you understood it and developed a super code for me. Your code is not just sorting by ascending /descending the order but doing a real calculation to find out a sequence that you can use to create a nice template layout. I cannot thank you enough man. You have helped me a lot. You are a genius. :)

Comment: Please check the "Problem" part of my question. If I use the array that I shown in the problem part, I get duplicate values. Thanks

Comment: Well, this was quick and dirty proof of concept, bugs were expected. I fixed it, but it is not production-grade code so I encourage to implement it on your own :)

Answer (score 2):

The question is:

> I want to sort this array in a way that the sum of any number of back
>   to back "grids" is equals to 12.

You may try this (using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php))

```
$records = array(
    array("postId"=>"1","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"2","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"3","grid"=>"6"),
    array("postId"=>"4","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"5","grid"=>"3"),
    array("postId"=>"6","grid"=>"12"),
    array("postId"=>"7","grid"=>"3"),
);
```

You have number `3`4 times, nimber `6` 2 times and number `12` once.

```
// Sort (ASC)
usort($records, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['grid'] - $b['grid'];
});
```

[**DEMO-1 (ASC)**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NATz9d) (`3+3+3+3=12`, `6+6=12`, `12=12`).

```
// Sort (DESC)
usort($records, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['grid'] - $a['grid'];
});
```

[**DEMO-2 (DESC)**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GEw6z0) (`12=12`, `6+6=12`, `3+3+3+3=12`).

Output after sort using (ASC) :

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 7
>         [grid] => 3
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 5
>         [grid] => 3
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 4
>         [grid] => 3
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 2
>         [grid] => 3
>     )
>
> [4] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 3
>         [grid] => 6
>     )
>
> [5] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 1
>         [grid] => 6
>     )
>
> [6] => Array
>     (
>         [postId] => 6
>         [grid] => 12
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: @kingkero, This sorts in the way `OP` wants it to be, all grids are in the right  order `3,3,3,3,6,6, 12`.

Comment: @kingkero, `OP` wants the array to be ordered by `grid` and it could be `ASC` or `DSC` but all the values of `grid` should produce the result `12` when you apply `add`, so `3+3+3+3 = 12`, `6+6=12` and `12=12`.

Comment: Yes, grids should result in 12. Your comparison doesn't do that but just sorts from lowest to highest number

Comment: @kingkero, It doesn't matter how, I did what `OP` asked for, am I wrong ? This gives you the desired result, I compared the values of grid.

Comment: It gives the desired result for the example data set, but not generally.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel, I really don't get it, what is the question. `OP` asked for this thing with the an `array` he provided. If this is wrong then `OP` should rephrase his question and I would definitely change/delete my answer.

Comment: The question is `I want to sort this array in a way that the sum of any number of back to back "grids" is equals to 12.` and i did that exactly.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right, but I'm sure the answer does not help. If the OP only was interested in this particular array, he would sort it by hand once and be done with it. Having 25k reputation you have to be kidding :)

Comment: @WolfgangStengel, I'm not kidding but can you gimme an example of array that won't be same result using this function, maybe I didn't understand but you can help me to understand it, so i can think of a different way or could delete the answer but I should know the difference and this way I can learn, answering doesn't only give you reps but also teaches you everyday and this way i learned from this community.

Comment: I apologize, indeed you simply need to sort descending to get the desired result for all examples I can think of. Somehow I thought a 9 should be possible as well (as it's a multiple of 3) but the OP clearly excluded this. Kudos.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel, it's ok and no need to apologize, we all are developers here and high reps doesn't make/proof me better than someone with low reps :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera Thank you very much for your help and thanks to Wolfgang Stengel as well :)

Comment: @black_belt, You are welcome :-) BTW, did it solved the problem ?

Comment: @black_belt, asking because i noticed you accepted the answer and then undone it so kind of confused :D

Comment: Yes both your answer and Wolfgang Stengel's answer worked for me, I have accepted your answer because you answered the question first :) Thanks a lot :) I wish I could be a PHP expert like you guys

Comment: Sorry it accidentally happened :)

Comment: @black_belt, It's ok, now it's green again :-)

Comment: @kingkero, can you tell me where I was wrong that you have down voted me :p

Comment: @SheikhHeera I think kingkero was right. Your code just only sorts from lowest to highest number. Imagine a sequence like this `6,3,3,3,6,6` if you sort this the way I wanted it should be like this `6,6,3,3,6,3` `(6+6 =12 3+3+6= 12, 3 is remaing)` but you code is just sorting it like this `6,6,6,3,3,3` .

Answer (score 1):

This solution first sorts by grid size descending and then brute forces it's way down by testing each remaining element against the sum so far for each row:

```
$sum=0;
$grouped=array();
usort($records, function($a, $b) { return $a['grid']<$b['grid']; });
while ($records)
{
    $next=reset($records);
    if ($sum) foreach ($records as $next) if ($sum+$next['grid']<=12) break;
    $grouped[]=$next;
    $sum+=$next['grid'];
    unset($records[array_search($next, $records)]);
    if ($sum>=12) $sum=0;
}
```

**Update**

Turns out that sorting in descending order is enough to solve the requirement using only 3, 6 and 12 elements. A 12 as well as a 6 followed by a 6 stand alone, and all other combinations are filled up with remaining threes. (For some reason I thought the algorithm would have to be able to deal with nines as well.) So this is all you need:

```
usort($records, function($a, $b) { return $a['grid']<$b['grid']; });
```

Granted this makes for a very boring grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please tell me how to use your solution because `print_r($records);` is not giving me any result :)

Comment: The records are put into `$grouped`.

Comment: Please imagine a sequence like this `6,3,3,3,6,6` if you sort this the way I wanted it should be like this `6,6,3,3,6,3` `(6+6 =12 3+3+6= 12, 3 is remaing)` but your code is just sorting it like this `3,3,3,6,6,6`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP >= 5.3.0 you can do this with `usort()` and closures (or globals as a hack). Given `$records`:

```
$running_length = 0;
usort( $records, function( $a, $b ) use( $running_length ) {
    $running_length += $a["grid"];
    if( $running_length >= 12 ) return( true );
    return( false );
});
```

If you visualize "grid" parameter as a string length, the end result, `$records`, becomes ordered like:

```
...            3
...            3
......         6
...                3
......             6
...                3
............  12
```

Given randomness of available chunks, you may want to sort this array first from smallest-to largest and then see whether it gets arranged better for you. This method obviously doesn't detect fragmentations and blocks that don't fit --- or can't resolve to fit.

Comment: How on earth does this work? ;-) You're not supposed to know the order in which the array elements are passed into the comparison function?